# Getting reference to control from function

Tags: vb.net

My application has a form which contains 4 tabs and each tab has a DataGridView (DGV) within it. There is also a panel of controls which sit outside of the tabs and are used for all the DGV controls.

I need to make sure that the code updates the correct DGV based on what the user is looking at. I currently do this for any events or functions where I need to do some work on a DGV:

```
Dim dgv As DataGridView = GetCurrentDGV(TabControl.SelectedTab)

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.SelectedRows
    'Do work on row
Next
```

And this is the function `GetCurrentDGV()`:

```
Private Function GetCurrentDGV(ByRef tab As TabPage) As DataGridView

For Each control As Control In tab.Controls
    If control.GetType Is GetType(DataGridView) Then
        Return CType(control, DataGridView)
    End If
Next

End Function
```

There are a number of things I don't like about this.

Firstly, it is slow. I'm not exactly sure why as each tab only contains a DGV and nothing else (so the loop through controls is only a single item which should return on the first loop).

Secondly, there's a chance my function doesn't return anything which will give a null reference.

I am trying to avoid hard-coding the relationship between tabs and DGV but before I go down that route, are there better ways I could be doing this?

Comment: I don't think it's really a better way to do it, but you could initialize the tab-dgv relationship once at load and store it to use it in the `GetCurrentDGV` function. If the `For Each` loop is the part slowing you down, you could avoid it without hardcoding by doing this.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I'll look into it. In truth I haven't worked out which part of the function `GetCurrentDGV` is the slowest bit. I suspect it's slow because I'm returning a DGV into a new variable (`Dim dgv`) which means I'm creating a copy of the DGV, albeit temporarily.

Comment: Pretty sure the dgv you dim is a Reference in this case. In VB class are Reference Types. Also you didn't made any extra cloning manipulation, and you didn't Dim the dgv as a new one to be filled. I don't think this the culprit!

Comment: You can use the `DataGridView.Enter` event, set the current DGV reference there.  You cannot search the `TabControl.Controls` collection without getting a null reference sometimes. Not very useful, either.

Comment: As laancelot explained all classes (and therefore _controls_) are reference types, which means that they are _accessed and passed by reference_. Your `dgv` variable doesn't actually hold your entire `DataGridView`, but merely a pointer pointing to a specific location in memory saying _"this is where you can find it"_. Cloning the entire `DataGridView` requires much more effort than this.

Comment: Thanks all. I didn't think I would be copying the whole dgv but wasn't entirely sure. It must be the looping through controls that is slow. I'll look into setting a public variable using the DataGridView.Enter event, although I'll need to be sure of when it's triggered when nested in a tab page.